# Truth value between two statements

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $p$ be the statement: "Good food is not cheap" and $q$ be the statement: "Cheap food is not good".

Is $p \iff q$?

My intuition is said, Yes, since $q$ is the contraposition of $p$, where
$p$ is equivalent to: "If the food is good, then it's not cheap", and $q$ is equivalent to: "If the food is cheap, then it's not good.

Comment: $A \implies B$ if and only if $(\neg B) \implies (\neg A).$  See [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, Sir. I already state it in my attempt above. So, is it correct, Sir?

Comment: Yes, except that I would not have expressed as $p = q$.  Instead, I would have expressed it as $p \iff q$, which signifies that $p$ is true if and only if $q$ is true.

Comment: @user2661923 Got it. Thanks a lot, Sir.

Answer (score -1):

Good food is not cheap does not imply that bad food must be cheap, it can also be expensive.

Likewise cheap food is not good does not imply expensive food is good, it can be bad.

Thus p is not equivalent to q.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are not implication?

Comment: @PitikKepit: They do not imply each other.